# how can i move column data to another table and set its id to foreign key column in first table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I had table application that one of the columns names allowed_command ,
then I create another table application_command and want to separate allowed_command column and move to second table 'application_command'
in addition, application table has foreign key from application_command
so , I need to copy value of allowed_command to application_command table then put its id to first table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate new table creation makes no sense. I recommend you to drop it and create new instance during data copy.

Step 1. Create new table and copy data into it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE application_command ( 
    application_command_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    allowed_command VARCHAR(255) )
SELECT DISTINCT allowed_command
FROM application;
```

Step 2. Create column for foreign key.

```sql
ALTER TABLE application 
    ADD COLUMN application_command_id BIGINT,
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_allowed_command (application_command_id)
        REFERENCES application_command (application_command_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Step 3. Set the relation values.

```sql
UPDATE application
  JOIN application_command USING (allowed_command)
SET application.application_command_id = application_command.application_command_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60661aae250012bcc4c9f72c1f6e2cb0

Now you can drop `application.allowed_command` column.

Comment: This could be true if the column data was different, in this case some recordes have same data

Comment: @haniehMoafi Your question is too general. So the answer is general too, and it describes one of possible ways to solve, and only approximately. If you need in more detailed description then you must give more details - structures, data examples, desired final state... and the best way as separate question.